# Need some help creating an audiosprite through cygwin/node.js on Windows 7

Tags: windows, node.js, audio, cygwin, sprite

I'm trying to make an [audiosprite](https://github.com/tonistiigi/audiosprite), but somehow I'm overlooking some basic thing somewhere, and I can't for the life of me find out what it is, googling around on the error I'm getting gets me 100's of unrelated results, so I'm sorta hoping somebody here can help me along.

I'm running on 64bit Windows 7 Pro, I've just installed the latest Cygwin (1.7.32) and Node.JS (0.10.32) for 64bit half an hour ago, and now I'm trying to actually use them, but I'm running into issues.
At first I thought (hoped) a simple restart would resolve things, but sadly it doesn't, I've also checked the PATH variable, and it has npm listed, so that's not it either.

here's what I'm doing, and getting:

```
olivier@MV-VFX-01 ~
$ cd audiosprite-stuff/

olivier@MV-VFX-01 ~/audiosprite-stuff
$ audiosprite *.mp3
cygwin warning:
  MS-DOS style path detected: C:\Users\olivier\AppData\Roaming\npm/node
  Preferred POSIX equivalent is: /cygdrive/c/Users/olivier/AppData/Roaming/npm/node
  CYGWIN environment variable option "nodosfilewarning" turns off this warning.
  Consult the user's guide for more details about POSIX paths:
    http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#using-pathnames

events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: spawn ENOENT
    at errnoException (child_process.js:1001:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:792:34)

olivier@MV-VFX-01 ~/audiosprite-stuff
$
```

So first I'm browsing to a directory (inside home/olivier) that has the mp3's I want to bake an audiosprite with.
After that I simply try the most basic possible audiosprite cmd, that should create an audiosprite from all mp3's in the current directory.
Overlooking the warning (least of my worries atm, and I can always fix that later) the return message from audiosprite is

```
events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: spawn ENOENT
    at errnoException (child_process.js:1001:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:792:34)
```

The issue is that I really don't know what to make of the above, like I said when I googled on (parts of) the error, I got completely random results, none related to audiosprite, and the ones that did relate to Cygwin had fixes for specific pieces of code, but not a general fix, which is kind of what I'm needing.

Does anybody have any clue what I'm missing here? do I need to add more stuff to my PATH variable perhaps? (at the moment it only mentions npm in the PATH variable, nothing else)
I've already tried some obvious things like running cygwin as administrator and even tried using 'command prompt' instead of cygwin, and while it does support all the cmds, I get the exact same errors there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, im just incredibly stupid..
I forgot to install FFMPEG, so ofc it couldnt make an audiosprite, durrrrr.

Resolved :)